# Bathroom radiator not turning off

Tags: heating, uk, radiator

We recently moved into a house in UK as tenants where if I turn on the heat the towel radiator keeps running despite turning the valve completely off. With winter approaching and energy prices going up, I would like to only heat the areas in the house that really need to be heated.

The radiator has a valve on one end and also a wire which is running from the radiator to the wall. The wall outlet doesn't have any switch, and only a receptacle for a fuse. I don't know if this means that the radiator is getting heated by electricity. The heat is turned on via a programmer called [Drayton LP 522](https://www.draytoncontrols.co.uk/product/lp522), but I am not sure if that can somehow control the circuit to this radiator. Any thoughts on what could be going on are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: radiator]

Comment: You are a tenant, which means this isn't your property. Ask the landlord for advice on how to adjust this so it's not heating all the time. If it requires a fix, it should be on him to maintain his property.

Comment: Leave towels on it, fully covering it, to minimize the heat used while you look into  having the landlord sort the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> if I turn on the heat the towel radiator keeps running

The towel radiator may be plumbed into the hot water circuit, rather than the central heating circuit, so you may find it's controlled by the hot water settings on your programmer rather than the central heating settings. (The idea here is that if you put the hot water on for a bath you probably want the towel radiator on but you might not want to heat the whole house, e.g. in the spring/autumn.)

> despite turning the valve completely off.

If this is your bypass radiator (Solar Mike's "safety" radiator - i.e. the one radiator in a system that is always on) the isolation valve needs to stay open. Some modern systems have an automatic bypass valve (either in the boiler or elsewhere) which means a bypass radiator is unnecessary. I expect your landlord will be delighted to pop round and explain the intricacies of the heating system.

> The wall outlet doesn't have any switch

There should be a switch somewhere for the electrical side of your dual fuel radiator. It may be a wall switch and it can be outside the bathroom (though hopefully near it). Look for something that seems to be a light switch but doesn't control any lights.

To confirm your discovery switch both central heating and hot water off for long enough for your radiators to cool down then try any mystery switches that don't control lights (one at a time).  Leave any such switches for several minutes to see if the radiator warms up or cools down.

Answer (score 0):

Bathroom towel radiators are often used as the "safety" radiator so that the boiler always has somewhere to dump heat if all the other radiators are shut off.

This is because the towel radiator is usually the one that is "on" most of the time. But practices vary between installers...

However, it also looks like that there is an electric heating element that is used to heat the radiator when the heating / boiler is turned off during the summer.